# Bootloader Flow Control C#

Tags: c#, embedded, bootloader

I'm working to program a MCU board over RS485.  I have the section of code done to access the bootloader no problem.  My problem is in this code:

```
int xon_off = ComPort.ReadChar();
if (xon_off == send_data) {
    int counter = 0;
    string line;
    System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("C:/Users/user/Desktop/x.hex");
    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != "    ") // reads until end of file
    {
        write_line: line = file.ReadLine();
        if (xon_off == send_data) {
            ComPort.Write(line);
            //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
            counter++;
            xon_off = ComPort.ReadByte(); // should be x_off
            error_check = ComPort.ReadByte(); // will give line complete or error
            xon_off = ComPort.ReadByte(); // should be x_on
        } else if (xon_off == stop_data) {
            read_again: xon_off = ComPort.ReadByte();
            if (xon_off == send_data) {
                goto write_line;
            } else {
                goto read_again;
            }
        }
    }
```

My issue is with the flow control (x_on/x_off/eof/etc).  The way the current code is, it can send a page error, and the tool keeps sending like it was nothing, so obviously my read/compare statements are off.  Can someone help me find out why when it sends a page error, my code thinks it's sending an x_on?

NOTE: x_on is a variable above set to 0x11 and x_off is a var above set to 0x13 just to clarify.

NOTE: Once I get this figured out, my next step is to remove the goto statements...they're gross I know, but they worked for here.

Comment: With a serial port you do not get an EOF until the connection is closed.  Don't use flow control it is archaic and won't work in most cases.  Don't use any flow control (neither hardware nor software).  If you are sending binary then do two things.  1) Make sure you have your stream class set to UTF8.  The default is ASCII which may give you an error like you are getting. 2) Add a byte count at beginning of message indicating how many bytes will follow.

Comment: Learn [ask], provide a [mcve]!

Comment: I"m not sending binary...it's all hex (Intel .hex file).  And you have to use a bit of flow control.  You have to wait for xon to send and then it sends either xoff or a page/line error.  You have to be able to tell when you get errors to resend lines.  Also, I'm just sending data through serial, so the EOF (or EOT) is on the .hex file itself, so the program needs to be able to decypher when it's reached the end and stop.

Comment: `goto` - here! Seriously? And don't add unrelated tags!

Comment: I'm asking for help to get rid of them!  As soon as I can figure out why my compare statements aren't working correctly in that block of code, I plan on making it a switch statement.  Please provide help instead of bashing code that I'm asking for help on.

Comment: It makes no sense to repair such a crap. You use xon_off, what should it be xon or xoff? You read bytes, assuming some content in it without checking it, you use file.ReadLine() twice, you doesn't use the `while` construct, instead you jumping with goto around. The whole construct is terrifying. Begin with a clean solution, I would recommend a state machine. Please take this as a constructive comment.

Comment: I am trying to take it as constructive.  My issue, I don't know how to mix chars/hex values in order to make a state machine.  Once I get that figured out, no issue getting rid of all the goto's etc.  This was just prototype to get something working, now I'm polishing it up and running into an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so from what I can understand, here's what the better option is:
First off, do remove the goto statements, they're horrindious and should never be used. As for the issue of not being able to mix chars/hex values, every char when brought in as an int will be assigned it's hex value (convert to int32 in the program).  When the bootloader sends the 0x11, it will more than likely send it as a char, which will come into your software as an unprintable ASCII char, but still have the 0x11 if you use your debugger and see what it's actually coming in as.  So my suggestion is to do a readbyte, then do a convert to int32 in software, and do a switch statement/state machine for what you want done.

Comment: Makes sense, I'll try that out and update if needed!